# Write BigQuery query results into table using python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I want to write a results of a BigQuery query, stored in txt file, into BigQuery table.
I'm passing query text as a variable into below function, but get the following error:

error_info=method + ' ' + url) google.cloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Required parameter is missing (POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/jobs)

What am I missing?

The function:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import uuid

def async_query(query, dataset_id, dest_table, project_Id):


    # configuration json
    query_data = {
        "configuration": {
            "query": {
                "query": query,
                "defaultDataset": dataset_id,
                "allowLargeResults": True,
                "destinationTable": {
                    "projectId": project_Id,
                    "datasetId": dataset_id,
                    "tableId": dest_table
                    },
                "createDisposition": 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                "writeDisposition": 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
          }
        }
    }

    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query_data)
    query_job.use_legacy_sql = False
    query_job.begin()
    wait_for_job(query_job)

    # Drain the query results by requesting a page at a time.
    query_results = query_job.results()
    page_token = None

    while True:
        rows, total_rows, page_token = query_results.fetch_data(
            max_results=10,
            page_token=page_token)

        for row in rows:
            print(row)

        if not page_token:
            break
def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()  # Refreshes the state via a GET request.
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can fix defaultDataset in your configuration as below

   ```
   # configuration json
   query_data = {
       "configuration": {
           "query": {
               "query": query,
               "defaultDataset": {
                   "projectId": project_Id,
                   "datasetId": dataset_id
                   },
               "allowLargeResults": True,
               "destinationTable": {
                   "projectId": project_Id,
                   "datasetId": dataset_id,
                   "tableId": dest_table
                   },
               "createDisposition": 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
               "writeDisposition": 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
         }
       }
   }
   ```

Note: "projectId": project_Id is optional in defaultDataset

2. the whole defaultDataset is also optional and in your case you can just omit it as in

   ```
   # configuration json
   query_data = {
       "configuration": {
           "query": {
               "query": query,
               "allowLargeResults": True,
               "destinationTable": {
                   "projectId": project_Id,
                   "datasetId": dataset_id,
                   "tableId": dest_table
                   },
               "createDisposition": 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
               "writeDisposition": 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
         }
       }
   }
   ```

see more in [configuration.query.defaultDataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.defaultDataset)

Answer (score 1):

I have got it to work with the following solution of adding the destination table as a bigquery.Table in the queryjob

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import uuid

def async_query(query, dataset_id, dest_table, project_Id):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query)
    query_job.use_legacy_sql = False
    dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id, client)
    table = bigquery.Table(dest_table, dataset)
    query_job.destination = table
    query_job.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
    query_job.begin()
    wait_for_job(query_job)

    # Drain the query results by requesting a page at a time.
    query_results = query_job.results()
    page_token = None

    while True:
        rows, total_rows, page_token = query_results.fetch_data(
            max_results=10,
            page_token=page_token)

        for row in rows:
            print(row)

        if not page_token:
            break

def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()  # Refreshes the state via a GET request.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's that `defaultDataset` is actually an object, so you'll need to set the `datasetId` field inside (this is probably what is triggering the error).

Can you try correcting that and see if it helps? You can see the [complete options for the `query` API in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query).